# Returning all the elements with the specific attribute using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

So, I have an `XElement` within an `Xml` file that looks something like this:

```
... More parent nodes  
<item cid="0x14c8" name="A" id="0xaf4b6f8">
    <item cid="0x57c" luid="2001"/>
    <item cid="0x578" luid="2000" value="0"/>

    <item cid="0x14fa" name="B">
            <item cid="0x57a" luid="2024" value="1.00"/>
            <item cid="0x579" luid="2025" value="0"/>
            <item link="0xb199640" cid="0x474" luid="5372"/>
            ...More descendants
    </item>
```

Now, I want to return an `IEnumerable<Element>` object of the elements that only contain the attribute `link` using `XPath`

In my `query`, I'm doing:

```
return currentXElement.XPathSelectElements("//item[@link]").Select(item => new Element(item));
```

But it is returning all the elements from the complete document, not from the `currentXElement` which is the section that I'm trying to query.

What can I do? I have tried using `/item[@link]` too, and is not returning anything.

Thanks

**EDIT**:

At the end, as Sergey suggested,

```
return currentXElement.Descendants("item").Where(i => i.Attribute("link") != null).Select(item => new IpjItem(item));
```

Comment: is there a reason you need to use XPath?  You've got yourself all set up to simply use LINQ

Comment: Can you provide sample xml which reproduces your problem?

Comment: @Jonesy First I thought using `LINQ`, but I think XPath is more efficient to return all the links. How would you do it using Linq?

Comment: The thing is that I have too many descendants, and they could contain a link as well.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, Basically the complete document is just a huge file with elements called items. So, imagine items before, and after.

Comment: How do you assign the values to currentXElement? We need more code to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Well, I have a series of classes that populate the children from specific nodes, and right now, `currentXElement` contains the XElement with the attribute name = "A" and all its children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//item` expression selects item elements no matter where they are in the document. If you want to select items relative to current element, you should use full path. E.g.

```
xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("//item[@name='B']//item[@link]")
```

Here I assume that `//item[@name='B']` selects your `currentElement` (you should use expression which select your current element), and then with `//item[@link]` you are searching for descendant items relative to item with name `B`.

NOTE: I think pure LINQ will be better here

```
currentXElement.Descendants("item").Where(i => i.Attribute("link") != null)
```

Comment: What if I don't know the full path? I could have links in C, D... is there a generic way to select the attribute?